# Attach column from one DataFrame to another if col value from 1 within range of values given in the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000, 2001, 2002], 'city':['NY', 'AL', 'TX'], 'zip':[100, 200, 300]})  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000, 2001, 2002], 'city':['NY', 'AL', 'TX'], 'zip':["95-150", "160-220", "190-310"], 'value':[10, 20, 30]})
```

The main df is df1 and I want to add the 'value' column from df2 to df1 based off of a matching year, city, and zip. The problem is that the zip of df2 is given in a range and I want to attach 'value' only if df1's zip is within a given range. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried a few things like:

```
# Match indices so that new cols will attach when equal indices
df1 = df1.set_index(['year', 'city'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['year', 'city'])

# Split range of zip into a list
df2['zip'] = df2['zip'].str.split("-")

# Attach 'value' to df1 if df1's zip if greater than df2's min zip AND less than df2's max zip
df1['value'] = df2.loc[(df2['zip'].str[0].astype(int) <= df1['zip']) & \
                       (df2['zip'].str[1].astype(int) >= df1['zip']), 'value']
```

Which gives me this error: **ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects**

Answer (score 1):

Split and make sure their int

`df2[['start', 'end']] = df2['zip'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)`

Use Series.between

```
df1['value'] = df1['zip'].between(df2['start'], df2['end'])

   year city  zip  value
0  2000   NY  100   True
1  2001   AL  200   True
2  2002   TX  300   True
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That gives me this error even after sorting both indices 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects' also how do you get df1 value to be equal to the 'value' column of df2?

Comment: make sure all dtypes are int. To get the values from df2 into df1 you can merge on `[year, city]`